# Pandas replace all values in certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace all values in a certain column,

for example this is my dataframe

```
Label  A  B C
 1     2  3 4
 2     3  2 1
 4     4  4 4
```

I want to replace all values in Column C with another value, for example "NaN"

To do this, do I need to use something like `.ix` or `.iloc` ?

I tried this `rem = df.ix[df.C!='NaN'] = 'NaN'` ,  but it just returned a string "NaN"

Comment: you can simply do `df.C.fillna(value)`.

Comment: In your example `C` is a column, not a row. Do you want to replace in a row as your title states or in a column as your example shows?

Comment: @FabianRost yes sorry it should be column - question is marked as duplicate - found my answer in other question posted.